# Access Chromium OS source code in archive file

Tags: archive, chromium-os

I use Chrome OS for a lot of my programming (oddly enough, but I do), and I wanted to access the Chromium OS source code because I like Chrome OS, and I want to see the insides of how it works. Only problem is, I can't access the CLI to do all the checkout stuff, even though I can enable a Debian VM (I don't want to, because I use it for everything, so I don't want to mess it up), but I can extract a `.zip` or `.tar.*` file through a Chrome extension. So basically, I want to know how (and if) to access an archive file of the Chromium OS source.

Comment: Their repositories are here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/?format=HTML, when you click through to a particular one and a specific revision, it has a tgz link for download. But there's rather a lot of it, this is possibly not a practical approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no single archive provided for all of the Chromium OS source.  A single checkout is made up of 100's of independent git repositories listed here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/manifest/+/HEAD/full.xml

If you want a checkout, you'll need to follow the documentation:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/developer_guide.md